# Warning: setState(...): Expected the last optional callback argument to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`setState` callback does not behave as expected, `setState` provide a callback to be called after the state changes,
and the callback is an action of redux:

```
addressInput = e => {
 this.setState({
   address: e.target.value
 },
 this.props.filterSearch(this.state.address));
}
```

I get this error

> Warning: setState(...): Expected the last optional `callback` argument
>   to be a function. Instead received: [object Promise].

Comment: You are calling the function there. Thus the return value is given as the second argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It expect a "last optional callback argument to be a **function**".

Write it like this:

```
addressInput = e => {
  this.setState({
    address: e.target.value
  },
  () => this.props.filterSearch(this.state.address))
}
```